# Android / Java - adding scrollView while preserving XML formatting

Tags: java, android, android-linearlayout, android-relativelayout, android-scrollview

I'm attempting to implement a scrollView in my XML however I'm having a few issues:

If I replace the outermost LinearLayout with a scrollView - the program crashes with "ScrollView can host only one direct child". I've also tried replacing the inner most LinearLayout with a ScrollView I lose my formatting and it looks like this:

### Incorrect Implementation:

```
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:id="@+id/linearLayout"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:orientation="vertical"
    android:paddingLeft="@dimen/activity_horizontal_margin"
    android:paddingRight="@dimen/activity_horizontal_margin"
    android:paddingTop="@dimen/activity_vertical_margin"
    tools:context=".MainActivity" >

    <com.google.android.youtube.player.YouTubePlayerView
        android:id="@+id/youtubeplayerview"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content" />

    <LinearLayout
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:orientation="vertical"
        android:paddingTop="7dip" >

        <ScrollView
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:background="@color/white" >

            <TextView
                android:id="@+id/titleTv"
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:layout_alignTop="@+id/uploaderTv"
                android:background="@color/white"
                android:paddingLeft="5dp"
                android:paddingRight="45dp"
                android:text=""
                android:textSize="22sp" />

            <ImageView
                android:id="@+id/buyButton"
                android:layout_width="50dp"
                android:layout_height="50dp"
                android:layout_alignParentRight="true"
                android:layout_centerVertical="true"
                android:adjustViewBounds="true"
                android:paddingBottom="10dp"
                android:src="@drawable/buy_a_up_btn" />

            <TextView
                android:id="@+id/uploaderTv"
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:layout_alignParentLeft="true"
                android:layout_centerVertical="true"
                android:adjustViewBounds="true"
                android:paddingBottom="8dp"
                android:paddingLeft="5dip"
                android:paddingTop="55dp"
                android:textColor="@color/verylightgrey"
                android:textSize="16sp" />

            <TextView
                android:id="@+id/viewCountTv"
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:layout_centerVertical="true"
                android:layout_toLeftOf="@id/buyButton"
                android:layout_toRightOf="@id/uploaderTv"
                android:adjustViewBounds="true"
                android:paddingBottom="8dp"
                android:paddingTop="55dp"
                android:textColor="@android:color/black"
                android:textSize="16sp" />


            <EditText
                android:id="@+id/editText1"
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="40dp"
                android:layout_weight="1"
                android:background="@color/white"
                android:ems="10"
                android:hint="Post Comment" >

                <requestFocus />
            </EditText>

            <Button
                android:id="@+id/button1"
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:layout_alignBaseline="@+id/editText1"
                android:layout_alignBottom="@+id/editText1"
                android:layout_alignParentRight="true"
                android:background="@color/black"
                android:text="SEND"
                android:textColor="@color/verylightgrey" />


        <TextView
            android:id="@+id/name"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_weight="1"
            android:gravity="left"
            android:paddingBottom="4dp"
            android:paddingLeft="10dp"
            android:paddingRight="10dp"
            android:paddingTop="10dp"
            android:text=""
            android:textColor="@color/grey"
            android:textSize="20sp" />

        <TextView
            android:id="@+id/content"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_below="@id/name"
            android:layout_weight="1"
            android:gravity="left"
            android:paddingBottom="4dp"
            android:paddingLeft="10dp"
            android:paddingRight="10dp"
            android:paddingTop="10dp"
            android:text=""
            android:textColor="@color/lightgrey"
            android:textSize="16sp" />

        <TextView
            android:id="@+id/published"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_below="@id/content"
            android:layout_weight="1"
            android:gravity="left"
            android:paddingBottom="10dp"
            android:paddingLeft="10dp"
            android:paddingRight="10dp"
            android:paddingTop="10dp"
            android:text=""
            android:textColor="@color/verylightgrey"
            android:textSize="16sp" />
        </ScrollView>
    </LinearLayout>

</LinearLayout>
```

How might I implement a scrollView in a layout such as this while preserving the existing XML formatting?

### Correct/Working Implementation:

```
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:id="@+id/linearLayout"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:orientation="vertical"
    android:paddingLeft="@dimen/activity_horizontal_margin"
    android:paddingRight="@dimen/activity_horizontal_margin"
    android:paddingTop="@dimen/activity_vertical_margin"
    tools:context=".MainActivity" >

    <com.google.android.youtube.player.YouTubePlayerView
        android:id="@+id/youtubeplayerview"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content" />

    <LinearLayout
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:orientation="vertical"
        android:paddingTop="7dip" >

        <RelativeLayout
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:background="@color/white" >

            <TextView
                android:id="@+id/titleTv"
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:layout_alignTop="@+id/uploaderTv"
                android:background="@color/white"
                android:paddingLeft="5dp"
                android:paddingRight="45dp"
                android:text=""
                android:textSize="22sp" />

            <ImageView
                android:id="@+id/buyButton"
                android:layout_width="50dp"
                android:layout_height="50dp"
                android:layout_alignParentRight="true"
                android:layout_centerVertical="true"
                android:adjustViewBounds="true"
                android:paddingBottom="10dp"
                android:src="@drawable/buy_a_up_btn" />

            <TextView
                android:id="@+id/uploaderTv"
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:layout_alignParentLeft="true"
                android:layout_centerVertical="true"
                android:adjustViewBounds="true"
                android:paddingBottom="8dp"
                android:paddingLeft="5dip"
                android:paddingTop="55dp"
                android:textColor="@color/verylightgrey"
                android:textSize="16sp" />

            <TextView
                android:id="@+id/viewCountTv"
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:layout_centerVertical="true"
                android:layout_toLeftOf="@id/buyButton"
                android:layout_toRightOf="@id/uploaderTv"
                android:adjustViewBounds="true"
                android:paddingBottom="8dp"
                android:paddingTop="55dp"
                android:textColor="@android:color/black"
                android:textSize="16sp" />
        </RelativeLayout>
    </LinearLayout>

    <LinearLayout
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:orientation="vertical"
        android:paddingBottom="@dimen/activity_vertical_margin"
        android:paddingLeft="@dimen/activity_horizontal_margin"
        android:paddingTop="@dimen/activity_vertical_margin" >

        <RelativeLayout
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:background="@color/verylightgrey"
            android:orientation="vertical"
            android:paddingBottom="8dip"
            android:paddingLeft="8dip"
            android:paddingRight="8dip"
            android:paddingTop="13dip" >

            <EditText
                android:id="@+id/editText1"
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="40dp"
                android:layout_weight="1"
                android:background="@color/white"
                android:ems="10"
                android:hint="Post Comment" >

                <requestFocus />
            </EditText>

            <Button
                android:id="@+id/button1"
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:layout_alignBaseline="@+id/editText1"
                android:layout_alignBottom="@+id/editText1"
                android:layout_alignParentRight="true"
                android:background="@color/black"
                android:text="SEND"
                android:textColor="@color/verylightgrey" />
        </RelativeLayout>

        <TextView
            android:id="@+id/name"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_weight="1"
            android:gravity="left"
            android:paddingBottom="4dp"
            android:paddingLeft="10dp"
            android:paddingRight="10dp"
            android:paddingTop="10dp"
            android:text=""
            android:textColor="@color/grey"
            android:textSize="20sp" />

        <TextView
            android:id="@+id/content"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_below="@id/name"
            android:layout_weight="1"
            android:gravity="left"
            android:paddingBottom="4dp"
            android:paddingLeft="10dp"
            android:paddingRight="10dp"
            android:paddingTop="10dp"
            android:text=""
            android:textColor="@color/lightgrey"
            android:textSize="16sp" />

        <TextView
            android:id="@+id/published"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_below="@id/content"
            android:layout_weight="1"
            android:gravity="left"
            android:paddingBottom="10dp"
            android:paddingLeft="10dp"
            android:paddingRight="10dp"
            android:paddingTop="10dp"
            android:text=""
            android:textColor="@color/verylightgrey"
            android:textSize="16sp" />
    </LinearLayout>

</LinearLayout>
```

Answer (score 0):

**ScrollView can host only one direct child** means that you should have only one View inside it. In the incorrect implementation you have TextView, ImageView, etc inside the ScrollView, thus the errors.

If you want to scroll some Views together then put them inside a layout like `LinearLayout` that you have under `YoutubePlayerView`. Then put that layout inside the ScrollView. Thus the code should be

```
<ScrollView
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:background="@color/white" >
<LinearLayout
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:orientation="vertical"
        android:paddingTop="7dip" >
// code

</ScrollView>
```